# React Nextjs change active className if selected or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to change the className of each component Card i have by clicking on them. If one is selected, the others one will not be and have their default className.

How my component Card is called :

```
const UserBookingData = ({ bookings }: any) => {  
    return (
        <div className="col-span-6 py-2">
            {bookings?.map((booking: any) => (
                <Card key={`cardKey${nanoid()}`} booking={booking} />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

component Card :

```
const Card = ({ booking} : any) => {
    const bookingDate = moment(booking?.startAt);
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
    const getBookingRef = (ref: string) => {
        setSelected(false);
        zusContext.setState({
            bookingRef: ref,
            bookingLoaded: true
        })
        setSelected(true);
    };
    
    return <div onClick={() => getBookingRef(booking?.ref)} className={`my-1 py-3 px-3 flex items-center rounded-lg ${selected ? 'cursor-default bg-white-dark' : 'bg-white group hover:bg-white-dark cursor-pointer'}`}>
        <div><svg className="w-14 fill-current text-white-dark4" viewBox="0 0 150 150"><path d="M 75, 75 m -75, 0 a 75,75 0 1,0 150,0 a 75,75 0 1,0 -150,0"/></svg></div>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between w-full">
            <div className={`ml-3 ${selected ? '' : 'flex flex-col'}`}>
                <div className="flex">
                    <div className={`text-blue text-xs px-2 py-[3px] rounded-md ${selected ? 'bg-white' : 'bg-blue-light group-hover:bg-white' }`}>{bookingDate.utc().format('DD MMM YYYY')}</div>
                </div>
                <div className='truncate text-sm font-medium pt-1 max-w-[160px]'>{booking?.space?.title}</div>
                <div className="text-sm text-dark text-[13px]">{booking?.space?.host?.firstname}</div>
            </div>
            <div><svg className="ml-3 mr-1 w-2 fill-current text-blue" viewBox="0 0 150 150"><path d="M 75, 75 m -75, 0 a 75,75 0 1,0 150,0 a 75,75 0 1,0 -150,0"/></svg></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
}
```

I tried with the hook selected, but the problem is, if i clic on one, it doesn't go back to his default className when i select another one.

I think it might be because it's not re rendered ?

Comment: can you create a codesandbox example?

Comment: @mocherfaoui no problem, [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-tamas-hfgn1s?file=/src/App.js) when i clic on one, i want it to turn it green then go back to red when i click on another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best approach here is to manage the state at the parent component(`UserBookingData`) and use `booking.ref` to know which card is selected:

```
// UserBookingData
const UserBookingData = ({ bookings }: any) => {  
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");
    return (
        <div className="col-span-6 py-2">
            {bookings?.map((booking: any) => (
        <Card
          key={`cardKey${nanoid()}`}
          booking={booking}
          selected={selected}
          setSelected={setSelected}
        />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
// Card component from codesandbox
const Card = ({ booking, selected, setSelected }: any) => {
  const color = selected === booking.ref ? "green" : "red";

  const getBookingRef = (event: any) => {
    setSelected(booking.ref);
    console.log(event.currentTarget.className);
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{ marginTop: "10px", backgroundColor: `${color}` }}
      onClick={getBookingRef}
      className={`default ${selected ? "green" : "red"}`}
    >
      {booking.space.host.firstname}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

you can see a working example here  [image: Edit xenodochial-brattain-0xl5m6]